# Can I keep my app in Testflight during approval process

Tags: ios, testflight

Does anyone know if you can keep your app in TestFlight during the approval process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. It even remains in TestFlight after your app has launched subject to the 30 day time limit.